# Easiest way to send mail from Linux Server

Tags: ubuntu-server, postfix, sendmail, mail-server

I want my server to send me email alerts every time it does things such as run a backup. I have tried to setup programs like Sendmail, Postfix, etc on my Ubuntu Server box and it is really a pain for me to get it working. Is there any online service or some easy gateway where my server can send email alerts? If not, is there any easy scripts to get a Linux mail program up and running?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're having trouble configuring the standard mail programs, you can use a command-line SMTP client such as [**sendEmail**](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/). Along with the address, message, and other data, simply specify an SMTP server. You can use [**GMail**](http://gmail.com) along with a username and password for example.

Here are the available command-line switches:

[image]

Comment: *Sweet* screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Your message"|mail -s "subject of the message" your@address.domain
```